# Mongoose .save() doesnt affect the entry in mongodb but doesnt show any errors

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to add likes and dislikes button in my demo project using Nodejs mongoose and Mongodb.

An AJAX call is made everytime the user clicks on either the liked or disliked button.

Each user has an array named postsReacted which contains objects with keys as "id" which is "id" of a camp and "reaction" which is either "likes" or "dislikes" depending on the button he pressed.

req.params.mode is a string which is either "likes" or "dislikes", each camp has a total count of "likes" and "dislikes" which is being updated.
The foundUser.save() callback runs without a problem however when i check through mongodb shell it doesnt update the "reaction" of that user , this only happens when the last else condition is executed, works fine for other cases.

The route is : "/:id/count/:userId/:mode"

req.params.id is the camp's mongodb id, req.params.userId is a user's mongodb id , req.params.mode is either "likes" or "dislikes" depending on what button was clicked.

Campground Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Schema for campgrounds
var campSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: String,
    likes: Number,
    dislikes: Number,
    image: String,
    location: String,
    lat: Number,
    lng: Number,
    description: String,
    author: {
      id:{
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
      },
      username: String
    },
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"                              // Model's Name
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Camp", campSchema);
```

User Model :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   postsReacted: []
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Route:

```
Camps.findById(req.params.id, function(err,foundCamp){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        req.flash("error", "Couldn't do this event, some error occured");
        res.redirect("back");
    } else{
        var interchangable = {"likes":"dislikes", "dislikes":"likes"};
        Users.findById(req.params.userId, function(err, foundUser) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                var index = foundUser.postsReacted.findIndex(function(post){
                    return post.id.equals(foundCamp._id);
                });
                if (index===-1) {    // When he hasnt reacted to this camp.


                    foundUser.postsReacted.push({id: foundCamp._id , reaction: req.params.mode});
                    foundCamp[req.params.mode]+=1;
                } else {   // If he has reacted to this camp

                    if (foundUser.postsReacted[index].reaction === req.params.mode) {     // He has clicked the same button of his older reacion so removing his reaction


                        foundCamp[req.params.mode]-=1;
                        foundUser.postsReacted.splice(index,1);


                    }else {    // When the user clicked the opposite button so his reaction needs to be changed     // When this runs foundUser.save() doesnt seem to work


                        foundCamp[interchangable[req.params.mode]]-=1;
                        foundCamp[req.params.mode]+=1;
                        foundUser.postsReacted[index].reaction=req.params.mode;
                    }
                }
                foundCamp.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Camp Updated");
                    }
                });
                foundUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("User Updated");
                        console.log(foundUser.postsReacted);
                    }
                });
                console.log({likes: foundCamp.likes, dislikes: foundCamp.dislikes});
                res.send(JSON.stringify({likes: foundCamp.likes, dislikes: foundCamp.dislikes}));
            }
        })
    }
})
```

The problem is with foundUser.save() command in the code below , it works when either index===-1 condition or when foundUser.postsReacted[index].reaction === req.params.mode condition is met however when the last else is run the foundUser.save() doesnt update the reaction of the user in the database even though callback is run and there are no errors.

Comment: Do you have some unique index in that collection of mongodb?

Comment: I would like to see your req.params and your models, it's hard to tell why it's failing from just this snippet.

Comment: I have added my user and campground models and also included the route and explanation of my req.params. Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to work around my problem by actually creating a copy of the postsReacted array and then using .set() method on foundUser to replace my old postsReacted array with the new updated one. Works like a charm now!